# Smart TV browsers support?

Tags: browser

I surfed google and tried to find information but unfortunately failed to do so,

so now I'm asking here: *does anybody know where can I find information what kind of features does standard Smart TV browsers support?*

Like is there any support matrix like caniuse.com but for TV's?

I managed to find out that most of them really sucks, but I want to know by how much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? http://html5test.com/results/television.html